# How to Search Using Multiple Parameters While Including Nulls in Results in SQL-Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to construct a simple query that will allow the user to filter a list of clients based on demographic information. It seems to me that `LIKE` would be the simplest solution, for instance:

```
SELECT D.Name
FROM demographics D

WHERE D.City LIKE @cityVar
AND D.Sex LIKE @sexVar
AND D.Age LIKE @ageVar
...
```

Variables are passed into the query using combo boxes; therefore if the user decides not to filter based on any given parameter, I simply pass `'%'` to the variable, effectively escaping that line in the `WHERE` clause.

However, this does not work if I would like to return rows containing `NULL` values in filtered fields.  For instance, if `D.Employer` has a value of `NULL`, the client is unemployed; but passing `'%'` to `@employedVar` (meaning that the user would like to return both employed and unemployed clients) ignores all rows where `D.Employer` is `NULL`.

How would I construct the logic of the `WHERE` clause in order to account for a large number of parameters while still allowing the user to escape filtering on any given parameter, all the while including `NULL` values when appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest would be to do something like this

```
SELECT D.Name
FROM demographics D
WHERE (D.City LIKE @cityVar OR @cityVar == '%')
    AND (D.Sex LIKE @sexVar OR @sexVar == '%')
    AND (D.Age LIKE @ageVar OR @ageVar == '%')
```

It is important that you **do not** use something like

```
SELECT D.Name
FROM demographics D
WHERE ISNULL(D.City. '') LIKE @cityVar
    AND ISNULL(D.Sex, '') LIKE @sexVar
    AND ISNULL(D.Age, '') LIKE @ageVar
```

Passing the values into a function will made it so SQL Server is unable to use any indexes that you may have on these columns.  This will result in inefficient query plans and poor performance.

Comment: In the first example, swapping the order of the ORs may improve performance (due to short circuiting), but I'm unable to test it right now.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you. How about interpreting `null` in the procedure to indicate that the user wants everything *except* `null`. In other words, if the user didn't specify anything, let's give them back everything with a value. So something like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ((@parm1 IS NULL AND field1 IS NOT NULL) OR
       (field1 LIKE '%' + @parm1 + '%'))
```

This query will return all rows that *have a value* if the user didn't specify anything, but if they did it will run the `LIKE`.

This just means that from the application, if the user doesn't specify anything (or maybe in your case specifies *all*) you send `null` to the procedure.